# python mysql DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rrror

Tags: python, mysql

so i have these pieces of Python code:

```
id=10001
ip="10.0.0.1"
up=[80, 5555]
down=0

sql = "INSERT INTO ip(id, ip, open, closed) VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE open=VALUES('%s');" % (id, ip, up, down, up)
```

and when i run it it errors with:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''[80, 5555]')' at line 1")
```

note: when i remove:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE open=VALUES('%s');
```

it runs just fine

any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from `VALUES()`.  The argument is a column name:

```
INSERT INTO ip(id, ip, open, closed)
    VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE open = VALUES(%s);
```

However, I would expect the right query to be:

```
INSERT INTO ip(id, ip, open, closed)
    VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE open = VALUES(open);
```

Note:  `open` is a keyword although it is not a reserved word.  In my opinion that makes it a poor choice for a column name.

Comment: if i do:    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE open = VALUES(open); then how would i set 'open' to "[80, 5555]"

Comment: `VALUES(open)` would be whatever value is passed in for the `open` column in the update.  This would *normally* be what you would want for the `on duplicate key` part, so my suggestion is just an educated guess.